# How do I get the list of ids in a particular class using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

e.g.

```
<div class="myclass" id="div_1"></div>
<div class="myclass" id="div_2"></div>
<div class="notmyclass" id="div_3"></div>
```

I'd like to end up with array something like ["div_1","div_2"]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After selecting `$(".myclass")`, you can use the `.map()` method <sup>[[docs](http://api.jquery.com/map/)]</sup> to take the `.id` of each element. This will return a jQuery array-like object containing the ids.

```
var ids = $(".myclass").map(function() { return this.id; });
```

Add `.toArray()` <sup>[[docs](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/)]</sup> to the end if you need a real array.

Comment: Your solution is much more concise then mine. Good job.

Answer (score 1):

```
var IDs = [];

$('.myclass').each(function(){
    IDs.push( this.id );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides `.map` you need `.get()` if you want an array in the end:

```
$('.myclass').map(function() { return this.id; }).get();
```